# "Double-tap to wake" does not work after a few hours of non-use on Realme

Tags: settings, screen, touchscreen, realme

I always use the "Double tap to wake" feature on my Realme device running on Android 13. But lately, the feature suddenly cannot be used after my device has not been used in a few hours (usually when I sleep).

After I look at **Settings > About phone > Status > System uptime**, it shows a time of about 2 or 3 hours active system, where it should have shown more than 2 days. Even though I'm sure if I don't reboot my device.

Is this normal?

Comment: "*Even though I'm sure if I don't reboot my device.*" your device could have reboot by itself. I don't know which device you're using since you haven't mentioned it, but Samsung has a setting "Auto optimization" that will reboot the device automatically when it is not being used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I use realme, in my case can it be caused by the battery settings?